# Don't let me complete reviews while I'm banned from editing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, edits, edit-ban

I'm not going to get in the debates and discussions about the ban itself.  ( I don't dispute it or the length or why) I'd suggest that if you ban my edit ability for 7 days I think you should also take away my ability to do reviews. Otherwise it's like grading an English paper without a red pen.

As a secondary question, what should I do for things I spot in the interim?

For the full details keep reading below:

Per my learning lessons from yesterday on different post ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178494/why-do-my-edits-keep-getting-rejected%20here)), I got the 7 day ban on editing.  There is no dispute or misunderstanding about that. The pitfall of this is that my ability to conduct reviews on new poster activity was NOT taken away, which is odd but no complaint from me just yet.  The resulting dilemma is that now as a reviewer or even going across pages I encounter things that I now properly understand need to be edited, and can't.

I can make the suggestion in a comment to adjust the formatting, and did so on the new poster review (and I won't perform any others until I get some feedback from this question). I suppose the best thing here is to skip it so someone else can fix the formatting later even if not me.  Rejecting it seems harsh and clearly unfair to the user and just wrong.  Flagging it for a moderator seems like a waste of moderator time. But I'm happy to do that if that's the best course of action.

In short, should I bookmark stuff like this to fix later once my ban is lifted?
(Doesn't this essentially encourage me to get off the site completely for the week and then repeat my old ways, as opposed to actually being given the opportunity to demonstrate I've 'learned what I did wrong'?)

Comment: Just a note, (I'm the one who upvoted, I agree with you) but the actual point of your question is in the last paragraph. You might want to make it more prominent; people stop reading towards the end unless you flag up that they must.

Comment: Case in point: I didn't read the last paragraph until I saw the comment from @ben

Comment: Which is why I flagged it in a comment @Andrew :-), knowing how often I get bored before the end of a post and start reading the comments instead.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @benisuǝqbackwards; I've updated the post a bit and retitled it as well. I started to realize that. Initially the question was what should I do until I realized I shouldn't even be able to do anything :-)

Comment: You're completely correct, it's very problematic having people go through the review queues who are forced to half-ass the reviews that require editing.

Comment: Also, kudos for coming up with this very productive post from a less-than-ideal situation!

Comment: "Skip" sounds like your best bet in this situation, honestly -- you don't currently have the tools available to take the best course of action on that post, and you wouldn't normally approve it.

Comment: @JimDagg Yeah you're right, I should pretend it is in a language I don't know and do what I do for them and skip them :-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implemented in build rev `2014.5.7.2223` on meta and `2014.5.7.1592` on sites.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update!

Comment: Better late than never! :)

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a badge for having your first feature suggestion being implemented, but then again I can't possibly comprehend the can of spam that would open from badge hunters

Comment: @UpAndAdam feel free to [meta-tag:feature-request] it. but now you've missed your chance to suggest it _and_ get it awarded as your first accepted/implemented [meta-tag:feature-request]... for ever...

Comment: lol.. that would have been very very funny. I think I can find a way to move on :-p